# IIS Intel Hex Core X64 Windows 2003

Tags: iis, hardware

Have windows 2003 r2 x64 running on dual intel hex core processors. right now its an app/web box, and it runs an asp.net site from a vendor.  my questions is, should i question the vendor why the it appears not all processors are getting a workout when hitting the site or is it a tweak i need to make on the iis/windows side:

[Screencast of procs](http://screencast.com/t/YzY2OTE4MGIt)

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at your screen cast, I'm a little surprised that there appears to be no activity at all on the majority of the processors - if the app was ignoring them or it was a bug in IIS then I might expect to see some small level of activity on all procs as the OS distributes tasks across all the cores available to it, with spikes based on your app activity only on some of them. But that isn't the pattern your screen-cast suggests is happening.

First thing to do might be to isolate if it's the base server (whether software or hardware) that's the problem here. There's several applications out there for benchmarking systems that can max out the processor cores... give one of those a go and if it only ever has activity on the first 4 cores as per your current screen-cast then your problem is more fundamental than the application... and if the problem isn't here then you'll be able to tell the developer what you've done to eliminate this as a possibility.